# A quantia de bytes durante uma leitura de arquivo varia de acordo com o modo escolhido?

Tags: c, arquivo

Em C, se eu abrir um arquivo em modo binário, lê-lo byte-a-byte e depois pegar o arquivo e ler em modo de texto, a quantidade de bytes vai ser diferente? Se sim, por que?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 5):

De maneira alguma, o arquivo tem a quantidade de bytes que ele tem, não importa o modo de leitura.

O que muda é que ler no modo texto há um tratamento para o indicador de mudança de linha que será interpretado conforme o sistema operacional. De resto nada difere. Obviamente que a tradução do indicador de mudança de texto pode variar de ter 1 ou 2 bytes e pode ser que o uso adote como 1 caractere sempre, mas aí é algo específico, circunstancial e sobre caracteres e não byte.